# How to import the data in disk.frame folder into R environment

Tags: r, disk.frame

There is a  folder 'C:\tmp_flights.df' that created by disk.frame package  , how to import the data into R environment again ? Thanks!

[image]

Below code created the disc.frame folder

```
  library(disk.frame)
    library(nycflights13)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(dplyr)
    library(disk.frame)
    library(data.table)
    
    flights.df <- as.disk.frame(
      flights,
      outdir = "tmp_flights.df",
      overwrite = TRUE
    )
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing how you created this folder (with fake data for ex)?

Comment: The data *is* in the R environment. After the code you showed, you can us `flights.df` in R using ‘dplyr’ verbs. — Did you check the documentation? It explains this.

Comment: Thanks, I mean when I exit R environment  and  reopen R, flights.df will not exist, but the flights.df exist in harddriver.  I want to use the harddriver data directly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `disk.frame` reads in an existing disk.frame folder.